# Unexpected Padding Swift UI List in NavigationView

Tags: ios, xcode12, swiftui

Simple list embedded in navigation view renders as expected:

```
NavigationView {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Row 1")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Row 2")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Row 3")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

But as soon as I add navigation bar button, I get unexpected paddings around the List.

```
NavigationView {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Row 1")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Row 2")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Row 3")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Add") {}) 
    }
```

[image]

Where are those paddings are coming from and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default `listStyle` for that combination. You should explicitly set that to `plain`:

```
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```